# What is the most efficient way to render a streamed video in SceneKit iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, video-streaming, scenekit

I'm working on a SceneKit app which shows a streamed video. In it I create a plane, attach a UIImage to it and then save the CALayer. Later, I get a compressed video stream, which I decompress into a CGImage. I then update the contents of the CALayer with the new CGImage. This all works, however the frame rate is pretty slow, and it doesn't appear to be a streaming or decompression issue.

**My question is**: Is there a faster, more efficient way to do this? I have transformed the SCNPlane both rotating and offsetting it. However, those should just be matrix updates and shouldn't change the render time as you have to go through the same matrix for rendering the SCNPlane in its original coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Converting to `UIImage` or `CGImageRef` is a costly operation. It creates a CPU representation of the image in a non-optimal format, and then requires another  conversion to a GPU representation (`MTLTexture`). SceneKit supports taking `AVPlayer` instances as the [`contents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395372-contents) of a material property. It should be the simplest and most efficient way to map a video onto a plane.

**Update:**
If your app pipeline is built around `CVImageBufferRef` (a.k.a `CVPixelBufferRef`) then `CVMetalTextureCache` and `CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` are the APIs you should leverage to efficiently produce `MTLTexture` instances to set as the `contents` of material properties.

Comment: digging deeper... The video decompressor is yielding a stream of CVPixelBuffer, which I convert to a  CGImageRef via VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer. I don't think I can feed the pixel buffer directly into an AVPlayer.